# Parse curl response with sed

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, curl, json

I'm trying to call a JSON API with the following `curl` command on macOS:

```
curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

It returns something like this:

```
{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}
```

I would like to extract the IP address from this response and run another `curl` command with this.

```
curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json | curl http://my.api.com?query=<IP RESULT>
```

Some of my failed attempts involve piping the result through a `sed` command with a regular expression.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have GNU tools?

Comment: osx @terdon dont have preinstalled jq

Comment: why don't you just use `curl https://api.ipify.org` which returns your IP directly... (just asking)

Comment: @pLumo Agree 200%, im going still to leave the question because parsing a json response with unix default tools in an easy way stills has interest for me

Comment: @Imnl Sorry, but what is "a `bash` tool"?  If you mean you only want to use utilities built into `bash`, then you will find it _extremely_ difficult to correctly parse JSON.

Comment: @Kusalananda edited, i tried to say unix default tools.

Comment: `jq` is the easiest, most robust, and stable way to parse JSON on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use command substitution instead of piping. On a Linux machine, I would use:

```
curl "http://my.api.com?query=$(curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json | grep -oP 'ip":"\K[0-9.]+')"
```

And on a machine that doesn't have GNU tools (e.g. macOS), one of:

```
curl "http://my.api.com?query=$(curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json | sed -E 's/.*ip":"([0-9.]+).*/\1/')"
```

Or even

```
curl "http://my.api.com?query=$(curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json 2>/dev/null | tr -d '"' | sed 's/.*ip:\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/')"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' | jq -r '.ip'
```

This would use `jq` to extract the value associated with the top-level `ip` key in the JSON response from `curl`.

You could then use this to make your other `curl` call:

```
ipaddr=$( curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' | jq -r '.ip' )
curl "http://my.api.com?query=$ipaddr"
```

Note also that URLs should always be quoted on the command line as they may contain `?` and `&` and other characters that the shell would treat specially.

`jq` is available through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on macOS.

---

Or, you could, [as pLumo suggests in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585096/parse-curl-response-with-sed#comment1089550_585096), just don't request a JSON formatted response from `api.ipfy.org`:

```
ipaddr=( curl 'https://api.ipify.org' )
curl "http://my.api.com?query=$ipaddr"
```